# @Font-face not working

Tags: css, asp.net, iis, font-face

I have been looking online to see if anyone else has had the same problem and they have but when i have used the answered code it still isn't working and im thinking is it something in IIS.

I have added this font face to my CSS.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
src: url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.ttf')  format('embedded-opentype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I have created my folder with my font files in there.

I have had alook at 'MIME TYPES' on IIS and have added all the types of files but it still doesn't work.

Has anyone else had this problem and could help me.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati Been out of office i have commented back, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Serving fonts from an IIS server**

If you are serving fonts from an IIS server, you'll need to add ‘.woff’ with a MIME type of ‘application/x-font-woff’ to your IIS installation, even though WOFF doesn't have a MIME-type. IIS refuses to serve anything that it doesn't have a MIME type for.

**IIS 6+**

```
.woff application/x-woff
.svg image/svg+xml
```

**IIS 7.5**

```
.ttf    application/font-sfnt
.eot    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
.otf    application/font-sfnt
.woff   application/font-woff
```

So after than since it's a **google font** the one you are using, have you tried just to load it in

**HTML**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or **CSS**

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

And then use it in your stylesheet?

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Also if you planning to load it on IE, pasted from google fonts documentation:

***Note:*** For best display in IE, make the stylesheet  tag the first element in the HTML  section. In IE, if the link is placed after  tags, the entire page will block and not display anything until the font is loaded.

Comment: I have added the files formats into IIS and then added the line at the top of my HTML but it still isnt working.

Comment: It seems to be deleting it when i go to restart the site on IIS.

Comment: Is it deleting this <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> ?

Comment: I thought it was deleting the MIME file type but its not. I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: It works on Chrome as i just tested it just it doesnt work on IE. Is it the order of the css lines?

Comment: If you delete the CSS you wrote and just test <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: If for instance you open in your browser http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300 you will see the CSS output

Comment: Try first without the local reference of the font file. :)

Comment: IIS deletes my MIME TYPE after like 5 minutes. why is this?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running?

Comment: I bet you are running an IIS reset after adding ? If you did, don't because the reset will reset also the MIME types.

Comment: No i dont run a restart. I looked at the website and followed the steps but the MIME types on the properties is greyed out.

Comment: Well, strange. Not sure how can I help you further on this :)